# Generating Softdeleteable query with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Tags: php, symfony, soft-delete, doctrine-extensions

I'm expecting, it should update deleted_at field when I've executed `DELETE` query. And it should add `deleted_at is null` condition to end of SELECT query. But its really delete rows with a silly condition. What is wrong?

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete("AppBundle:ReportRow", "r")
    ->where("r.date <= :date")
    ->andWhere("r.balance is null")
    ->andWhere("r.name = :name")
    ->setParameters(array("date" => $date->format("Y-m-d"),
                            "name" => $user->getName()))
    ->getQuery();

$output->writeln($query->getSQL());
```

Here is the output:

```
DELETE FROM report_row 
WHERE (date <= ? AND balance_id IS NULL AND name = ?) 
AND (report_row.deleted_at IS NULL) // really ?? its delete query dude!
```

Here is my configuration

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        ...
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been submitted to the developers and is currently pending since 2014 at https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1125

**Explanation:**

When you use the `QueryBuilder` to create a `DELETE` statement, you bypass the `onFlush` event listener which is used to prevent physical deletion of the entry, as you are no longer working within the entity manager when using `$em->remove($entity)`, but instead are manually issuing an SQL statement.

The result is that the softdeletable filter is no longer managing the intent of your query but is still aware of the `deleted_at` metadata.

---

To resolve the issue you must use a Query Hint with the `SoftDeleteableWalker` as explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md)

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete("AppBundle:ReportRow", "r")
    ->where("r.date <= :date")
    ->andWhere("r.balance is null")
    ->andWhere("r.name = :name")
    ->setParameters(array("date" => $date->format("Y-m-d"),
                            "name" => $user->getName()))
    ->getQuery();

$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            \Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Query\TreeWalker\SoftDeleteableWalker::class);

$output->writeln($query->getSQL());
```

Results:

```
UPDATE report_row 
SET deleted_at = '2017-10-03 15:06:48'
WHERE (date <= ? AND balance_id IS NULL AND name = ?)
```